# Using Greatest Common Divisor fun

Tags: functional-programming, lazy-evaluation

euclid :: Int -> Int
euclid n = length (filter (gcd n == 1) [1 .. n-1])

gcd :: Int -> Int -> Int

..

Comment: The Haskell prelude already defines a `gcd` function for you, no need to define it yourself.

Comment: *“the length of all the common divisors that is == 1”* --- I don't understand. What do you mean by this?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? (If it's Project Euler problem 73, the optimal solution is not computing any `gcd`s, by the way.)

Comment: If you cannot explain your problem in english, then you will not be able to explain it to a computer, in any language, either.

Comment: Updated now. Yes, the initial post was too vague. Cheers

Comment: Your error comes from "gcd x 0 = x".  The "x :: Int" is the inferred result but the type declaration of "gcd :: Int->Int->Bool" expects Bool.  I expect that "gcd x 0 = (x==1)" is what you ought to have typed.

Comment: @ChrisKuklewicz Put that as an answer. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're looking for [Euler's totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function), simply call

```
euler_fi1 n = length $ filter ((==1).(gcd n)) [1..n-1]
```

The linked WP article gives a formula for calculating this directly:

```
euler_fi n = let 
   fs = Data.List.nub $ factorize n 
   pr = n * product [p-1 | p <- fs] 
  in Data.List.foldl' div pr fs
```

You'll need a `factorize` function for that:

```
factorize n | n > 1 = go n (2:[3,5..])  where
  go n ds@(d:t)
    | d*d > n    = [n]
    | r == 0     =  d : go q ds
    | otherwise  =      go n t
        where 
          (q,r)  = quotRem n d
```

Next optimization is to use primes list instead of `(2:[3,5..])`.

Comment: Hi, I keep getting: "Couldn't match expected type `Bool' against inferred type `Int'
    In the expression: x
    In the definition of `gcd': gcd x 0 = x"

Answer (score 1):

Your error comes from "gcd x 0 = x". The "x :: Int" is the inferred result but the type declaration of "gcd :: Int->Int->Bool" expects Bool. I expect that "gcd x 0 = (x==1)" is what you ought to have typed.